# Is this necessarily a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T$ be a linear endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, suppose there exists non-zero vectors $u,v,w$ with $T(u)=u, T(v)=2v, T(w)=3w$. Is $\{u,v,w\}$ necessarily a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1: Direct brute force.

Let $T:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ be a linear map as above.
We examine the linear combination $au+bv+cw=0$, if we can show that this equality holds only for $a=b=c=0$, then $u,v,w$ are linearly independent and hence a basis for $\mathbb R^3$.

We apply the map $T$ to both LHS and RHS of $au+bv+cw=0$, we get equality

$au+2bv+3cw=0$.

Another application of $T$ to above, we get equality

$au+4bv+9cw=0$.

To summarize, we have linear system of vector equations:

$au+bv+cw=0$

$au+2bv+3cw=0$

$au+4bv+9cw=0$,

Since $u,v,w$ are nonzero vectors, you can solve above be elimination/substitution and show that $a=b=c=0$.

Approach 2: Eigenvectors.

Notice $u,v,w$ are eigenvectors of $T$ of distinct eigenvalues. Arrive at your conclusion.